# Create JSON data using JQuery, AJAX and php

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to get data from my database in a JSON format, but instead I am getting the data in below image.

[image]

I am using this code:

```
$("#priorityPieForm").submit(function(event) {
  var data = {};
  data = $(this).serialize();
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "dataFiles/priorityPie_data.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      priorityPieData = $.parseJSON(data["queryReturn"]);
      alert(priorityPieData);
      makePriorityPie(theme);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Always use `console.log()` to debug as `alert()` coerces the data to a string. Try `console.log(priorityPieData)`

Comment: And do not forget to look in console of the browser. CTRL + SHIFT +J in Chrome

Comment: i think you are getting the result correctly. on success you can show json data by  eg:data.name

Comment: if you use parseJSON function it creates javascript objects from string so you can't print out structure of object because alert convert js objects back to string anyway.

Comment: improve .. it can help https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "dataFiles/priorityPie_data.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {

      // Open your developer tools (F12) to see the the json data
      console.log(data);

      priorityPieData = data.foo;

      makePriorityPie(priorityPieData);
    }
  });
});
```